# Play and pause multiple audio file at the same time

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing a Music player app, in my app I want to play all the mp3 file on single button click. I was able to do it with MediaPlayer, but unable to pause all the songs using Pause button. How can I pause all playing songs at once

**Play button**

```
  for (int i = 0; i < InstrumentCountSize; i++) {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setDataSource(instruments_count.get(i));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

    }
```

**Pause button**

```
   if (mp != null) {
        try {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your single `mp` variable can only reference a single `MediaPlayer`, so your Pause button code is only trying to release the *last* `MediaPlayer` instance that you created. You need to keep references to all the `MediaPlayer` instances.

[UPDATED]

Something like this should work better:

```
// This needs to replace your "mp" variable.
List<MediaPlayer> mps = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();


// Play button code ....
// Make sure all the media are prepared before playing
for (int i = 0; i < InstrumentCountSize; i++) {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp.setDataSource(instruments_count.get(i));
    mp.prepare();
    mps.add(mp);
}
// Now that all the media are prepared, start playing them.
// This should allow them to start playing at (approximately) the same time.
for (MediaPlayer mp: mps) {
    mp.start(); 
}


// Pause button code ...
for (MediaPlayer mp: mps) {
    try { 
        mp.stop(); 
        mp.reset(); 
        mp.release(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
mps.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks, A lot it's working fine but there is only one problem that second audio playing after 2 or 3 seconds

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it makes sure all the media are prepared before you start playing them.

Comment: Thanks, now all the songs are playing simultaneously and pause button also working

Comment: what if i add sounds one by one and play simultaneously?

Comment: @Innocent `mp.setdataSource()` is being used in this code to add data sources one by one. If you have a more complicated question, you should create a new one.